# PHP foreach array and objects have me stumped

Tags: php, arrays, api, foreach

I'm currently working with the leafly API, and have run into a roadblock.

I'm pulling data from their API for dispensary reviews, with the following code

```
$data = wp_remote_get(http://data.leafly.com/locations/denver-relief/reviews?skip=0&take=10)
```

if I `var_dump` $data, I get the following (truncated so it isn't so long in this question)

```
array(5) {
    ["headers"]=> array(11) {
        ["server"]=> string(17) "openresty/1.7.4.1"
        ["date"]=> string(29) "Wed, 07 Oct 2015 12:37:51 GMT"
        ["content-type"]=> string(31) "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        ["connection"]=> string(5) "close"
        ["vary"]=> array(2) {
            [0]=> string(15) "Accept-Encoding"
            [1]=> string(81) "X-Requested-With, Accept, Host, X-Language-Locale, Prefer-Html-Meta-Tags, Version"
        }
        ["cache-control"]=> string(20) "public, max-age=3600"
        ["expires"]=> string(29) "Wed, 07 Oct 2015 13:39:24 GMT"
        ["last-modified"]=> string(29) "Wed, 07 Oct 2015 12:39:24 GMT"
        ["access-control-allow-origin"]=> string(1) "*"
        ["x-ua-compatible"]=> string(16) "IE=edge,chrome=1"
        ["content-encoding"]=> string(4) "gzip"
    }
    ["body"]=> string(2971) "{
        "reviews": [
            { "id": 435377, "username": "Nateju", "date": "\/Date(1438691404518+0000)\/", "meds": 5, "service": 5, "atmosphere": 5, "overallRating": "5", "shopAgain": true, "wouldRecommend": true, "easeOfRegistration": 0, "packagingQuality": 0, "firstVisit": false, "comments": "I will only shop at livewell because of its quality of good, positive staff, and chill environment. \n\nBen accommodated me when my I missed my number. As eel as making me feel welcome from beginning to end.\n\nCherdneaux was my budtender during this visit. Not only was she friendly but she found common interest and ASKED/CARED about what I was up to for the remainder of the day. Not many people take the time to ask, let alone care.\n#TheeBestDispensary", "starImage": "https://d3h17ltqi8v019.cloudfront.net/stars/5/240?color=fcc91d", "avatar": "https://d3h17ltqi8v019.cloudfront.net/profile/nateju/avatar/300" },
            { "id": 430268, "username": "fritzcrumb", "date": "\/Date(1437747908306+0000)\/", "meds": 3, "service": 3, "atmosphere": 2, "overallRating": "2.66666675", "shopAgain": false, "wouldRecommend": false, "easeOfRegistration": 0, "packagingQuality": 0, "firstVisit": false, "comments": "Did not like the vibe. Prices higher than average.", "starImage": "https://d3h17ltqi8v019.cloudfront.net/stars/2.66666675/240?color=fcc91d", "avatar": "https://d3h17ltqi8v019.cloudfront.net/profile/fritzcrumb/avatar/300" },
            { "id": 419409, "username": "imhungry", "date": "\/Date(1436456628062)\/", "meds": 5, "service": 5, "atmosphere": 5, "overallRating": "5", "shopAgain": true, "wouldRecommend": true, "easeOfRegistration": 0, "packagingQuality": 0, "firstVisit": true, "comments": "My gf and I stopped by here a little over a week ago. We aren't from Colorado, so they explained to us in detail what we could and couldn't buy. They were very professional and nice. We went in there a little nervous as this was our first time buying from a dispensary. I think his name was Brandon? Anyway, he made us feel right at home. If we ever come back to Denver, this is going to be our go-to dispensary. Very good prices and the staff make it a pleasure to shop there. Their medicines are top notch. Highly recommend!", "starImage": "https://d3h17ltqi8v019.cloudfront.net/stars/5/240?color=fcc91d", "avatar": "https://d3h17ltqi8v019.cloudfront.net/profile/imhungry/avatar/300" }
        ],
        "pagingContext": {
            "PageCount": 36,
            "TotalItemCount": 108,
            "PageIndex": 0,
            "PageNumber": 1,
            "PageSize": 3,
            "HasPreviousPage": false,
            "HasNextPage": true,
            "IsFirstPage": true,
            "IsLastPage": false
        }
    }"
    ["response"]=> array(2) {
        ["code"]=> int(200)
        ["message"]=> string(2) "OK"
    }
    ["cookies"]=> array(0) { }
    ["filename"]=> NULL
}
```

What I'm trying to do is pull in a foreach statement to cycle through each of the reviews, so I can display them on the page, pulling out only the info I want.

This is the code I've currently got, but it's giving me a `invalid argument supplied foreach()` error.

```
foreach( $data['body']->review as $review) { echo $review['username'] }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've only begun working with API's recently and can do some tasks, but this has stumped me for a couple of days now and I can't seem to get my head around it.

Thanks!

Comment: you are using key as 'review'. It should be 'reviews'

Comment: try to use `array_column( $arr, 'body' )`, that will collect all ["body"] elements in an array for you than use a foreach loop and you will get all reviews easily .if you think , I have not understand your question, you can let me know.

Comment: @meen I see that, and just tried to make it `reviews` but it still gives me the foreach() error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try...

```
$body = json_decode($data['body'],true);

//var_dump($body); exit;
//var_dump($body['reviews']); exit;

foreach ($body['reviews'] as $review) {
    echo $review['username'];
}
```

If that doesn't work there might be a problem with the json string. `json_decode()` will return `null` if it doesn't like the string you give it so try uncommenting the `var_dump`(s) to make sure you're getting an array back.

Answer (score 1):

The body contains JSON, so you need to use:

```
$json = json_decode($data['body'],true);
```

Then you can use:

```
foreach ($json['reviews'] as $review) {
    echo $review['username'];
}
```

Comment: I just tried this and it gives me an `invalid argument foreach()` error. I also did `echo $json;` and it only says `Array` on the screen.